# can a method be declared with static type argument in java ? if no, why?

Tags: java

can a method be declared with static type argument in java ? if no, why?

ex:

```
class A
{
    void m(static int x)
    {
         System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the use case for this?

Comment: i want to know why it is not possible.

Comment: What would this mean?  The keyword `static` in Java has specific meanings in different contexts but this is not a context in which it is defined.  What does it mean to _you_?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible and I cannot think of any valid use case for doing it.

It may make sense to make the method static in order to implement a singleton pattern.

```
class A
{
    static void m(int x)
    {
         System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Then it could be used without having to instantiate A as follows:

```
A.m(1);
```

Alternatively you might want to make x immutable to avoid unexpected behavior.  This would be done using "final" as follows:

```
class A
{
    void m(final int x)
    {
         System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

But making x static would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't be allowed (compiler error) and it makes sense as well. The static keyword means that a variable will have only one instance in its scope and that instance is invisible outside that scope. Neither of this makes sense for a function argument.

§6.7.5.3/2: "The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is register."

Comment: i knew all those things which u mentioned above, but i just want to know why we can not pass static arguments. and also know the meaning of static.

Comment: You can't pass it because Java specification does not allow it and hence compiler will complain. Why Java specification does not allow it is already mentioned above in above replies.

Answer (score 0):

> Static members are considered as class level members and gets loaded
>   in memory during class loading, which means it is desirable that it
>   shouldn't have dependency on the class instances.

So your class has member method `m` which need a `parameter` to be passed to execute the method body.

> If you declare a static member for it that doesn't make any sense
>   because it doesn't have any existence outside the method, class has no
>   information about it load time which severely violates all the rules stated
>   above.